# How to detect the incoming httpd Connection Counts of each VHOSTS?

Tags: apache-httpd, vhost

With RHEL and Apache (httpd), is there a way to:

- Detect which v.host (domain) is gaining how many incoming connections?

Because in this few days, I got a lot of incoming connections on the server being acknowledged by using:

- `ps aux | grep httpd -c`

  734

That means I have `734` incoming connections currently being handled by Apache but the problem is I have (lets say) 10 Vhosts (domains).

- So which domain is getting the high loads?

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the access log format to include the host string in the log.  Then it is a simple matter to sort and count by `vhost`. These are the `apache` configuration lies I use.

```
# Modified log format with virtual host, execution time, and query params
LogFormat "%v:%p %a %T %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" local

# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log local
```

This can be counted using a command like:

```
cut -d\t -f1 access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Or you can use `awk` (which allows selection by time of day and/or other data):

```
awk '{print $1}' access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Alternatively use separate access logs for each vhost.  A simple word count on the active access logs would answer your question.

To check the current activity enable the mod-status plugiyn and fetching the status using the URL `http://127.0.0.1/server-status`.  The output will include the last URL processed by each slot as well as its current state.  This information can be used to determine the current state.  Using the output of the URL `http://127.0.0.1/server-status?notable` may be easier to parse.

The command `w3m -dump http://127.0.0.1/server-status?notable` povides a nice text dump. However, the comamands `wget` or `curl` are commonly used for this kind of query.

Comment: Hi @BillThor will it show the *current* (live) number of connections (for each VHosts), please?

Comment: @夏期劇場 Using the server-status modules output will give the current state when run. I have updated my response accordingly.

Comment: does it give connection counts per Virtualhost?